# Why do large LMs use the transpose of the word embeddings matrix in the classification head?

Tags: distributions, natural-language, recurrent-neural-network, matrix-inverse, transformers

All literature, guides and tutorials describing the construction of language models have used two separate matrices for the input and output projections:

To project one-hot token IDs into hidden states, a matrix $U$ of size $\mathrm{VocabSize} \times \mathrm{HiddenDim}$ is used.
To project the hidden states back into vocab space prior to softmax, a matrix $V$ of size $\mathrm{HiddenDim} \times \mathrm{VocabSize}$ is used.

However, the source code for `transformers` in the Huggingface library shows a completely different process that uses only one matrix:

The classification head takes hidden states $h$ at the top of the Transformer stack and then performs $\operatorname{softmax}( \operatorname{MLP}(h) \cdot U^T+b )$ to recover the vocab probability distribution.

---

Why exactly does this work? Can the MLP and transpose of $U$ be considered some form of pseudo inverse process? And why have I not seen this in literature for modern Transformer architectures? Is this something that dates back to the first RNN-LMs and as such need not be described? And if so, why does every tutorial I've seen (both for encoder-decoder RNNs and Transformers) not describe this and instead opt for using two separate matrices? Could it be that this is harder to optimize due to weight sharing?

I would appreciate some insight on this and references to literature since I am unable to find anything myself.

Comment: This is called parameter tying. They’ve set U and V to be equal to each other as a constraint, which regularizes the model. It’s offered as a flag in the popular seq2seq libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer.

This practice is called parameter tying. They’ve set $U$ and $V$ to be equal to each other as a constraint, which regularizes the model. The information about token relatedness is assumed to carry over, at least to some degree, between the source and target—especially for related languages.

You ask about whether this dates back to "the first RNN-LMs". Not quite. A paper that describes the technique in the context of neural sequence models is [Press and Wolf (2017)](https://aclanthology.org/E17-2025/)—though it's older than that; machine translation folks had been using it in their toolkits since well before Press and Wolf's paper.

You also ask about the transpose—that's so that the matrices are conformant. The original matrix $U$ maps from vocabulary to a latent space; the $V := U^{\intercal}$ matrix maps back from a latent space to the vocabulary.

In terms of implementation and how widespread it is, it’s offered as a flag in the popular seq2seq libraries.

Comment: (+1) I also suspect that this kind of parameter tying speeds up how quickly $V=U^\prime$ are optimized, because they receive gradient signal from two parts of the model. Not sure if anyone has studied this conjecture, though.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming this works because given a one hot token vector $x$ multiplication by $U$ will essentially give us just one row/column (depending on features first or features last) of that matrix for our embedding $x'$, and applying the softmax to the product of $x'$ with $U^T$ will recover a distribution $y$ where $ArgMax(x)=ArgMax(y)$. So if the transformer stack produces embeddings close to the entries of $U$ we can easily recover the token index the embedding points to. Could applying something like Orthogonal regularization to $U$ improve convergence?

Comment: Your assumption about how this works is correct. That's why you'll often see an "embedding layer" implemented with an interface that accepts an integer and slices out the corresponding row of the matrix. On the output side, the embedding most similar to $h$ will correspond to the highest-probability token.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is more of a comment... I am a bit surprised that Keras does not have this kind of dual use in the layers and, as the OP says, all the tutorials online, even when claiming to build LLM as GPT, do independent layers. The corresponding keras layers of the transformers library do indeed embedding-embedding tying, but at the cost of ad-hoc command in the call. A possible alternative could be an initializer that provides the same variable to the embedding an unembedding layers.

Now, if one defines a metric to check the difference between embedding and embedding matrix, say

```
print("Misalignment:",
np.mean(np.square(np.transpose(unembedding.get_weights()[0])-embedding.get_weights()[0])))
```

it can be seen that it usually decreases during the training. So perhaps it is not provided because convergence is foreseen to happen in a natural way in a long training, and it only needs to be forced in a fine tuning or short training.

Also, it does not need to be forced as hard as installing a single layer, it is possible to promote the above metric to an additional loss, and then we have a sort of "elastic parameter tying"

Comment: "but at the cost of ad-hoc layers" is incorrect. `transformers.TFSharedEmbeddings` does not use AdHoc layers. OPT is an example that uses this keras layer for parameter tying.

Comment: @Avelina you are correct, I was thinking that it implies to use a new kind of layer, while in the deep all we want is to share a variable in two different layers. The advantage would be to get independent trainable flags.